# Why does laravel have the validation rule "nullable"?

Tags: laravel, validation, nullable

I'm a bit confused about the nullable rule. I remember in (very) old laravel versions there was no "nullable" rule. If a field wasn't "required", it was automatically nullable.

Isn't it true, that every field that is not "required", can always be null? Why do I have to declare that it is nullable?

For example if I check for "numeric" value and if the field is not "required", I have to make it "nullable".

Thank You!

Comment: Read here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Answer (score 0):

When you want to accept a value that can be a specific type or null, you can use the `nullable`.

For example :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
    'issue_date' => 'nullable|date'
]);
```

In the above example, the issue date can be nullable but if it's not null it must be a valid date.